# Mganeto2.3: getMaxPrice and getMinPrice not working give sql error

Tags: price, magento2.3.2

I try to get max price and min price from custom collection. Its working fine in magento 2.1.9 but after upgrade in magento 2.3.2 its give error.

See below Code

module block file,

```
class Wishlist extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{
protected $httpContext;
protected $_catalogProductVisibility;
protected $_productCollectionFactory;
protected $_categoryFactory;
protected $_imageHelper;
protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;
private $_objectManager;
protected $_filesystem;
protected $_imageFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $listProductBlock,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory,
    array $data = []              
)
{
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->listProductBlock = $listProductBlock;
    $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
    $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    $this->_imageHelper = $imageHelper; 
    $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
    $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->setCollection($this->getProductCollection());
    $this->setAllCollection($this->getAllProductCollection());
}
public function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();
/** @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager */
    $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
       'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
       'whishlist.view.pager'
    );
    if(isset($_REQUEST['product_list_limit']) && $_REQUEST['product_list_limit'] != ''){
        $perlimit=$_REQUEST['product_list_limit'];
    }
    else
    {
        $perlimit='18';
    }
    $pager->setLimit($perlimit)
        ->setShowAmounts(false)
        ->setAllCollection($this->getAllCollection())
        ->setCollection($this->getCollection());
    $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
    $this->getCollection()->load();
    $this->getAllCollection()->load();

    return $this;
}public function getProductCollection()
{
     $request =  $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');


    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');

    $collection->addStoreFilter()->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code' , 'attribute_value');
    $collection->addStoreFilter()->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code2' , 1);

    if(isset($_REQUEST['availability']) && $_REQUEST['availability'] == "purchased"){
        $collection->joinField('stock_item', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', 'qty=0');
        $collection->getSize();
        //echo count($collection);exit;

    }else if(isset($_REQUEST['availability']) && $_REQUEST['availability'] == "available"){
        $collection->joinField('stock_item', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', 'qty>=1');
    }
    else
    {

    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['cat']) && $_REQUEST['cat'] != "")
    {
        $collection->addStoreFilter()->addCategoriesFilter(["in" => $_REQUEST['cat']]);
    }
    //$this->_stockFilter->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);


    // Start Price Filter Code
    if(isset($_REQUEST['price']) && $_REQUEST['price'] != ""){

        $urlPrice = explode("-",$_REQUEST['price']);

        $minPrice = $urlPrice[0];
        $maxPrice = $urlPrice[1];

        $collection->addStoreFilter()->addAttributeToFilter('price' , array('gteq'=>$minPrice));
        $collection->addStoreFilter()->addAttributeToFilter('price' , array('lteq'=>$maxPrice));
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['product_list_order']) && $_REQUEST['product_list_order'] == 'price_high'){
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'desc');
    }
    elseif(isset($_REQUEST['product_list_order']) && $_REQUEST['product_list_order'] == 'price_low'){
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'asc');
    }
    elseif(isset($_REQUEST['product_list_order']) && $_REQUEST['product_list_order'] == 'a-z'){
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('name', 'asc');
    }
    elseif(isset($_REQUEST['product_list_order']) && $_REQUEST['product_list_order'] == 'z-a'){
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('name', 'desc');
    }
    else
    {
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
    }

    return $collection;
}
```

Phtml File

```
$productCollection = $this->getCollection();
```

if(count($productCollection) > 0)
{

```
$originalmaxPrice = $productCollection->getMaxPrice();
$originalminPrice = $productCollection->getMinPrice();
//$originalmaxPrice = '10';
//$originalminPrice = '9';
if(isset($_REQUEST['price']) && $_REQUEST['price'] != ""){
    $arr = explode("-", $_REQUEST['price']);
    $minPrice = $arr[0];
    $maxPrice = $arr[1];
}else{
    $maxPrice = $productCollection->getMaxPrice();
    $minPrice = $productCollection->getMinPrice();

}}
```

Error

```
 main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.min_price' in 'field list', query was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id), ROUND(MAX(e.min_price ) * 1, 2) AS `max`, ROUND(MIN(e.min_price ) * 1, 2) AS `min`, STDDEV_SAMP(ROUND((e.min_price ) * 1, 2)) AS `std` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 WHERE (e.min_price IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: I am getting the same error, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include final price data in your product collection as below:

`$productCollection->addFinalPrice();`

So the final code should look something like this:

```
$productCollection = $this->productCollection->create();
$productCollection->addFinalPrice();
echo $_productCollection->getMinPrice() . '-' . $_productCollection->getMaxPrice();
```